# Any idea what "[Instrument] colle Parti" means?

Tags: sheet-music, terminology

I'm trying to figure out what "[Previous instrument] colle Parti" means when changing instrument, but I found no information about it. Translation is "[Previous instrument] with parts", so my guess is to play the previous instrument alongside the other instruments. If you can confirm or correct me, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

[image: Image of "[Instrument] colle Parti" in the sheet music]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Tromboni colle parti" means, as you have found, "trombones with the parts."  In particular, it means that the three trombones (one each alto, tenor, and bass) should play the same notes as the respective parts of the chorus.

The snippet you've posted is from page 91 of the first edition of Mozart's Requiem.  The notation is required here because, before the page turn, they are playing the same pitches but different rhythms from their choral counterparts, so their notes are written explicitly on the staff.  Because the colla parte notation frees the trombone staves for other use, the trumpets and timpani are sharing these staves as well.

The instruction is for the person reading the score (the copyist or the conductor), not for the players.  The players' parts may or may not include an indication of what the chorus is doing; traditionally they would not.

Comment: A very small addition: parts for musician sometimes (not here though) has a "colla parte" or "colla voce" (with voice). This is and indication to the musician to play together with the solo instrument or the singer. (As for colla or colle, that is oldish italian grammar and a totally different question but I believe colla is more appropriate for single and colle for multiple).

Comment: @ghellquist yes, _colla parte_ is also used as an instruction for an accompanying part to follow a soloist.  I didn't mention this because it was already in the other (now deleted) answer.  As for grammar, Wiktionary will tell you that _colla_ itself [is old fashioned](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/colla#Etymology_1), but the plural being _colle_ is still good grammar in the modern language (as is the plural of _parte_ being _parti_).

Answer (score 5):

'Colla parte' is an instruction to double another instrument or voice, and the plural 'colle parti' an instruction for several instruments.
The other answer covers the use of the phrase in the example given, but there is another usage:
In operas and other vocal works or instrumental solos an instrument from the orchestra will often play along with the solo to support it. The instrumental part is marked 'colla parte' to indicate to the player that they should follow the  phrasing of the soloist.